# T-SQL interpretation in SSMS versus ADODB

Tags: sql, vb6, sql-server-2012, adodb

Context: SQL Server 2012, ADODB 2.8, VB6

I have a COM DLL written in VB6. (Okay, that's a problem in itself but that's not what I'm talking about right now.)

Certain statements executed via SSMS work fine. When executed via ADODB they fail. Examples are below:

```
UPDATE tblEvents SET EventStartDateTime = EventStartDateTime + CAST('-604800000' AS bigint), EventEndDateTime = EventEndDateTime + CAST('-604800000' AS bigint) WHERE (EventID = 41)

UPDATE tblEvents SET EventStartDateTime = 1400947200000 WHERE (EventID = 41)

UPDATE tblEvents SET EventStartDateTime = CAST(1399132800000 as bigint) WHERE (EventID = 41)

UPDATE tblEvents SET EventStartDateTime = (1400256000000) WHERE (EventID = 41)
```

The error I get from ADODB is

```
ADODB.Connection: Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are in conflict with one another.
```

The code implementing the ADODB call is as follows:

```
Function OpenRecordSet2(ByRef oDb As Variant, sQuery As Variant) As Object ''ADODB.Connection ADODB.Recordset
    Dim oRecordSet As Object 'ADODB.Recordset
    Set oRecordSet = CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")
    oRecordSet.Open sQuery, oDb, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockOptimistic
    Set OpenRecordSet2 = oRecordSet
End Function

Function OpenDatabase2(theConnection As Variant) As Object ' ADODB.Connection
    Dim oConnection As Object 'ADODB.Connection

    On Error Resume Next
    Set oConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    oConnection.Open theConnection
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Err.Raise OPENDATABASE_E_NOTFOUND, , Err.Description
    End If
    Err.Clear
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set OpenDatabase2 = oConnection
End Function
```

It's all using late-binding, that the CreateObject statements.

Should the settings be different for the connection or the recordset? That's about all I can think of right now (4:24 AM).

**10 HOURS LATER**

Well, it turned out to two things. One was a "." when I should have been using a ","; One of the times that JScript doesn't complain much is when you write a function with two parameters but you only send it one.

The other issue was that I was using the wrong [CursorType property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms677593%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Once I set that to adOpenDynamic, I was able to update the data.

Comment: There's likely some kind of translation/checking going on inside ADODB that isn't applied when you run the statements in SSMS. The ADODB code is messy but doesn't look obviously wrong. Is the EventStartDateTime field actually an int?

Comment: Could it be the driver or security type specified in the connection string?  http://piecesoeight.blogspot.com/2012/04/using-vb6vbscript-to-connect-to-sql.html

Comment: It's the `Dim ... As Object` that makes it late-bound, not the `CreateObject` i.e. you could've used `Set oConnection = New ADODB.Connection` and still be late-bound.

Comment: @wqw (blush) ok, learned something again. Thanks. So what would make it early-bound?

Comment: Dim ... As ADODB.Connection makes it early-bound.  You're binding to a type library at compile time when you declare as a type.  Otherwise, you're binding at run time.